# Don’t Hold Your Breath

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ‘Advanced’ Nuclear Reactors? Don’t Hold Your Breath
> With little hard evidence, their developers maintain they’ll be cheaper, safer and more secure than existing power plants

By Elliott Negin on July 23, 2021
Source: [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/lsquo-advanced-rsquo-nuclear-reactors-don-rsquo-t-hold-your-breath/)

Does "Don’t Hold Your Breath" mean "Don't be surprised"? It is odd that it seems to share the same meaning with "Hold Your Breath" to me. I am not sure.

Comment: I don't understand why you say *it seems to share the same meaning with "Hold Your Breath"*. That *(**non-negated**)* version has no currency as an idiomatic usage - it would only ever occur as a ***literal*** imperative in certain unusual situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use 'don't hold your breath' about a possible future event to express the opinion that the event is unlikely to happen in the near future. The journal is saying that cheaper, safer, and more secure advanced nuclear reactors, mentioned in an article, are not coming soon, despite what their developers say.

> don't hold your breath
>
> informal
> used to tell someone not to expect something to happen for
> a very long time:
>
> She said she'd get back to us, but don't hold your breath!
> She said
> she might finish by this afternoon but don't hold your breath.

[Don't hold your breath (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/don-t-hold-your-breath)

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is clear and consistent with other dictionaries' definition except the Cambridge, in which shouldn't it be "used to tell someone not to expect something to happen soon" rather than "used to tell someone not to expect something to happen for a very long time"?  "For a very long time" sounds odd here.

Comment: Cambridge says it differently. For a very long time, don't expect something to happen. It's good English.

Comment: Negators are tricky. In theory, _Don't expect (something to happen) for a very long time_ could mean "Don't except that the thing will happen and take a long time to happen"; but in practice it almost always means "Don't expect that it will happen until a long time has passed" - and therefore means the same as "Don't expect (something to happen) soon".